# MySQL invalid String error for specific Special Characters but not for others?

Tags: mysql, unicode

I have a simple mySQL database with a single table and row. The row is set up like so:

> utf8mb4_general_ci - varchar(255)

When I manually insert the following characters, it works fine:

> ☎ , इ ई , ∑

But when I attempt to insert characters like these:

> or

It doesn't work and gives me an Invalid String error. I found information on the first character [here.](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1d4dd/index.htm)

It states that the character belongs to the following block:

> MATHEMATICAL_ALPHANUMERIC_SYMBOLS

How can I detect characters like these to prevent them from being submitted by users. Is there a simple regex I can use?

Answer (score 0):

and  are in the range of `utf8mb4`. So, you need to establish the connection from your client to the mysqld server as being utf8mb4.  Since you have not said what your client is, I can't give you a specific answer.  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#python and the following sections may cover your client.  Be sure to use `utf8mb4` instead of `utf8`, but leave `UTF-8` alone.